# WCF service error while consuming service as client (SSL implemented)

Tags: wcf, service

I have developed a web service which returns xElements.

In WCF Service Page(To test this service use svcutil.exe........) WSDL link was

```
https://host_system_name.domain.com/Feed/Service.svc,
changed it to 
https://regName.domain.com/Feed/Service.svc. 
by adding <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/> in config.
```

Now wsdl is opening(wasn't b4 as mentioned in previous para) but while consuming the same service.....

```
ERROR WHILE IMPLEMENTING SERVICE:

The message with To 'https://host_system_name.domain.com/Feed/Service.svc' cannot be
processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.
Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
```

Here in error desc I am getting server's hostname, while in endpoints etc. registered site name has been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps -

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b5ae495b-f5fb-4eed-ae21-2b2280d4fec3/

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. I have mentioned https://RegSiteName.domain.com/virtualDir/ in endpoint and while implementing it requesting service i.e. "To" service was being referenced as https://server.domain.com/virtualDir/
Replacing absolute address with relative address in endpoint address resolved the issue.